# Javascript getElementById value setting getting reset on function return

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have a simple function to show / hide a div element. I have a javascript function to do that. I debugged this with Opera. The function sets the hidden value properly on the div element. I can see the div element disappear. However, when the function returns the div element reappears. The javascript function is in its own file:main.js:

```
function showhide(name){
    var elem = document.getElementById(name) ;
    if( elem.hidden == false ) {
        document.getElementById(name).hidden = true ;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(name).hidden = false ;
    }
}
```

The Html is:

```
<div class=wrap><p>
<div class=sidebar>
    <FORM><input type="submit" value="Toggle" onclick="showhide('specname');"/></FORM></div>
<div class=main>main Div
    <div id="specname">collapsible text</div></div></p></div>.
```

I have set debugging breakpoints in the javascript function showhide to see that the value is being set properly. But on function return, the value is reset.

It is probably something simple I am missing but can't seem to see it? Any ideas? Thanks!

**The answers solved my problem. I was missing the fact that the submit repainted the page and I lost my changes. I changed the type=submit to type=button. And I removed the form to just an input element with type button. That worked very nicely. Thanks everyone for your help!!! I really appreciate your answers!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using a submit control which will submit to the server and refresh the page.  You want to stop the submit or change the control type.  Both of the following should work.  I recommend the 2nd one.

Try this

```
<FORM><input type="submit" value="Toggle" onclick="showhide('specname'); return false;"/>
```

or this

```
<input type="button" value="Toggle" onclick="showhide('specname');"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following wont do anything in some browsers:

```
document.getElementById(name).hidden = true
```

change it to

```
document.getElementById(name).style.display = 'block' // and 'none' for the matching line
```

does that make it do what you need?

---

As others have pointed at, it is also submitting the page - either use a different element or change the function to start :

```
function showHide(e, name) {
     e.preventDefault();
     //do the toggle here
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because when you click the button the form submits and it refreshes the page ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a form just to have a button that does something. Instead, try using
`<button onClick="showhide('specname');">Toggle</button>` (and get rid of the form entirely)

Comment: Thanks people!! The solutions worked. I ended up using button rather than submit. Glad to know what was actually causing the problem! Really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your showhide().

```
function showhide(name){
    var elem = document.getElementById(name);
    (elem.style.visibility == 'hidden'?elem.style.visibility = 'visible':elem.style.visibility = 'hidden'); 
}
```

OR similarly:

```
function showhide(name){
    var elem = document.getElementById(name);
    (elem.style.display== 'none'?elem.style.display= 'inline':elem.style.display= 'none'); 
}
```

Maybe try them both and see which you need.

Cheers.